# Как сделать сортировку в парсере Avito?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Пишу парсер данных об биноклях в Avito. Помимо предложений о бинокле, парсится реклама. Парсится только первое объявление. Что я сделал не так?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import random

CSV = 'avito.csv'
HOST = 'https://www.avito.ru/'
URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/respublika_krym?s=1&q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8C+20&p=1'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params = ''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='item__line')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        name = item.find('div', class_="snippet-title-row").get_text(strip=True).lower()

        if 'Бинокль' in name:

            cards.append(

                    {
                        'title': item.find('div', class_="snippet-title-row").get_text(strip=True),
                        'price': item.find('div', class_="snippet-price-row").get_text(strip=True),
                        'city': item.find('div', class_="item-address-georeferences").get_text(strip=True),
                        'href': HOST + item.find('div', class_="snippet-title-row").find('a').get('href')
                    }
                )
            return cards
        else:
            continue
def save_doc(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Название', 'Цена', 'Город', 'Ссылка на товар'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'],item['price'], item['city'], item['href']])


def parser():
    PAGENATION = input('укажите кол страниц :')
    PAGENATION = int(PAGENATION)
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cards = []
        for page in range(1, PAGENATION + 1):
            print(f'парсим страницу:{page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'p': page})
            cards.extend(get_content(html.text))
            save_doc(cards, CSV)

    else:
        print('Сайт лежит ((')

parser()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return cards
```

Вынеси из цикла в тело функции

Comment: большое спасибо